# Layering a Bootstrap column on top of another column

Tags: html, css, css-position, bootstrap-5

How does one overlay a bootstrap column on top of another column, but also keep its size and responsiveness?

For example, I have 4 columns in a row:

[image]

When I click on the `Overlay btn`, it should show the `E` column over `B`:

[image]

I currently have this test code I am playing with:

Live jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8pmt6ck2/2/

```js
$(".a .btn").click(function() {
  $(".e").toggleClass("d-none");
});
```

```css
.one .a {
  background-color: red;
}

.one .b {
  background-color: blue;
}

.one .c {
  background-color: green;
}

.one .d {
  background-color: pink;
}

.one .e {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container one">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 a">
      <div class="vh-100 text-center">
        <span>A</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Overlay btn</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 b">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>C</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 d">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>D</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 e position-absolute d-none">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>E</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am using `d-none` for `E` because it does not take up space, otherwise it'll cause Bootstrap to think there are 5 columns, when it's actually 4 columns and one overlay column (on top of `B`).

The above code sort of works due to `position-absolute`, but it's in the *wrong location, and the column size is not the same as the other 4 columns (appears wider)*:

[image]

Part of the confusion also stems from the bootstrap documentation. It appears if I use `position-absolute`, I can only position things in certain quadrants of the screen, using `top-`, `start-`, `end-`, and `bottom-`:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/

But because I need this to be responsive and match the column width and such of existing columns in the row, those positioning classes don't help me much here.

---

**How can I overlay my `E` column properly? Ideally the solution should work for any number of columns in a row, not just 4 like I have above**.

Comment: Is it important that B is also visible when E is visible?

Comment: B should not be visible if E is overlaid on top. If I want visibility, I figure I can just adjust the opacity of E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning is often problematic and unnecessary. Just toggle the columns in standard layout.

```js
$(".a .btn").click(function() {
  $(".b, .e").toggleClass("d-none");
});
```

```css
.one .a {
  background-color: red;
}

.one .b {
  background-color: blue;
}

.one .c {
  background-color: green;
}

.one .d {
  background-color: pink;
}

.one .e {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container one">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 a">
      <div class="vh-100 text-center">
        <span>A</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Overlay btn</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 b">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 e d-none">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>E</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>C</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 d">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>D</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you actually need *both* columns visible, I'd propose toggling *contents* instead of columns. Here you will use absolute positioning. I'm also toggling the style class on the column.

```js
$(".a .btn").click(function() {
  $('.b-e').toggleClass('b e');
  $(".b-e .col-overlay").toggleClass("d-none");
});
```

```css
.one .a {
  background-color: red;
}

.one .b {
  background-color: blue;
}

.one .c {
  background-color: green;
}

.one .d {
  background-color: pink;
}

.one .e {
  background-color: orange;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container one">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 a">
      <div class="vh-100 text-center">
        <span>A</span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Overlay btn</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 b-e b position-relative">
      <div class="vh-100 col-overlay position-absolute d-none">
        <span>E</span>
      </div>

      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>B</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 c">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>C</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 d">
      <div class="vh-100">
        <span>D</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```